# "Got OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over tf.Tensor" while not obviously iterating over tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

OS: Manjaro Linux x64

CUDA: 11.0.3

TF/Keras: 2.4(.1)

Py: 3.8

Hello,
I'm trying to build some kind of W-VAE-GAN. I keep un running into that very same error over and over again and I already had that problem with Keras 2.3, interestingly NOT using TF/K 2.2. Unfortunately I need to use Keras 2.4 because I'm supposed to run my code on our university server with these exact TF/K and CUDA-Versions. At this point I'm just trying to make sure my code works as intended.

The error I get is the following, with the exact lines commented in my code:

```
...
Epoch 1/20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/wvaegan.py", line 282, in <module>
    gan.fit(gen_trans, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[callback])
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1100, in fit
    tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 828, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 871, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 725, in _initialize
    self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2969, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3361, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3196, in _create_graph_function
    func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 990, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 634, in wrapped_fn
    out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 977, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/wvaegan.py:190 train_step
        z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(clip_img) # <------ WHY NO ERROR HERE?
    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:505 __iter__
        self._disallow_iteration()
    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:498 _disallow_iteration
        self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
    /home/peer/Programmierkram/BA/Metal_GAN/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:474 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

What I do not understand is how it comes to this error in the first place, as I successfully executed the VAE-part using TF2.2 without any error like this, and, more importantly, there is no iteration over any tensor obvious to me. Even if I commented out the for-loop in my train_step the same error occurs few lines later in the same context. I have also tried decorating the def train_step() with @tf.function, yet nothing changed.

The code I used is the following:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import itertools
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image  as PIL


runOnGPU = 0

if runOnGPU==1:
    os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID"
    os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0"
    gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
    if gpus:
        try:
            for gpu in gpus:
                tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
        except RuntimeError as e:
            print(e)
else:
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = '-1'


path_clipped_train = os.path.join('./sinograms/clip')
path_transparent_train = os.path.join('./sinograms/transparent')

img_width, img_height = 512, 512
bottleneck = 1024 * 2
filters = (1024, 512, 256, 64)
filter_size = (3, 3, 3, 3)
batch_size = 4
epochs = 20
dsc_steps = 1
gp_w = 10.0
beta_v = 2
learning_rate = 125e-5
latent_dim = 2
input_shape = (1, img_width, img_height, 1)

dataset_gen1 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255, dtype="float32")
dataset_gen2 = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255, dtype="float32")

gen_trans = dataset_gen1.flow_from_directory(path_transparent_train,
                                             target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                             color_mode='grayscale',
                                             classes=[''],
                                             class_mode=None,
                                             batch_size=batch_size,
                                             shuffle=False,
                                             )

gen_clip = dataset_gen2.flow_from_directory(path_clipped_train,
                                            target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                                            color_mode='grayscale',
                                            classes=[''],
                                            class_mode=None,
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            shuffle=False,
                                            )


class Sampling(layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs):
        z_mean, z_log_var = inputs
        batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
        dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
        epsilon = tf.keras.backend.random_normal(shape=(batch, dim))
        return z_mean + tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var) * epsilon


def get_encoder():
    encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=input_shape[1:], name="encoder_input")
    enc = encoder_inputs
    for (numFilters, szFilters) in zip(filters, filter_size):
        enc = layers.Conv2D(numFilters, szFilters, activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(enc)
        enc = layers.BatchNormalization()(enc)
        enc = layers.Dropout(0.2)(enc)
    conv_shape = K.int_shape(enc)[1:]
    enc = layers.Flatten()(enc)
    enc = layers.Dense(bottleneck, activation='relu', name="bottleneck")(enc)
    enc = layers.BatchNormalization()(enc)
    z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(enc)
    z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(enc)

    latent_z = Sampling()([z_mean, z_log_var])

    encoder_model = keras.models.Model(encoder_inputs, latent_z, name="encoder")
    return encoder_model, conv_shape

enc_model, conv_shape = get_encoder()
enc_model.summary()


def get_decoder():
    latent_input = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    dec = layers.Dense(conv_shape[0] * conv_shape[1] * conv_shape[2], activation='relu')(latent_input)
    dec = layers.Reshape(conv_shape)(dec)
    for (numFilters, szFilters) in zip(reversed(filters), reversed(filter_size)):
        dec = layers.Conv2DTranspose(numFilters, szFilters, activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(dec)
        dec = layers.BatchNormalization()(dec)
        dec = layers.Dropout(0.2)(dec)
    decoder_outputs = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(dec)

    decoder_model = keras.models.Model(latent_input, decoder_outputs, name="decoder")
    return decoder_model

dec_model = get_decoder()
dec_model.summary()


def get_discriminator():
    dscr_input = keras.Input(shape=input_shape[1:])
    dscr = dscr_input
    for numFilters in filters:
        dscr = layers.Conv2D(numFilters, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', strides=2, padding='same')(dscr)
    dscr = layers.Flatten()(dscr)
    dscr = layers.Dense(1, activation="relu", name="dsc_end")(dscr)

    discriminator_model = keras.models.Model(dscr_input, dscr, name="discriminator")
    return discriminator_model


dsc_model = get_discriminator()
dsc_model.summary()


class GAN(keras.Model):

    def __init__(self,
                 discriminator,
                 encoder,
                 decoder,
                 latent_dim,
                 dsc_steps=dsc_steps,
                 gp_w=gp_w,
                 ):
        super(GAN, self).__init__()
        self.discriminator = discriminator
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.dsc_steps = dsc_steps
        self.gp_w = gp_w

    def compile(self,
                dsc_optimizer, enc_optimizer, dec_optimizer,
                dsc_loss_fn, enc_loss_fn, dec_loss_fn):
        super(GAN, self).compile()
        self.dsc_optimizer = dsc_optimizer
        self.enc_optimizer = enc_optimizer
        self.dec_optimizer = dec_optimizer
        self.dsc_loss_fn = dsc_loss_fn
        self.enc_loss_fn = enc_loss_fn
        self.dec_loss_fn = dec_loss_fn

    def call(self, data):
        ds = self.discriminator(data)
        e = self.encoder(data)
        d = self.decoder(e)

    def gradient_penalty(self, batch_size, ref_img, gen_img):
        alpha = tf.random_normal([batch_size, 1, 1, 1], 0.0, 1.0)
        diff = gen_img - ref_img
        interpolated = ref_img + alpha * diff

        with tf.GradientTape() as gp_tape:
            gp_tape.watch(interpolated)
            pred = self.discriminator(interpolated, training=True)

        grads = gp_tape.gradient(pred, [interpolated])[0]
        norm = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(grads), axis=[1, 2, 3]))
        gp = tf.reduce_mean((norm - 1.0) ** 2)
        return gp

    @tf.function # doesn't make any difference if decorating with that
    def train_step(self, data):
        trans_img = data
        clip_img = data
        batch_size = tf.shape(trans_img)[:1]

        for i in range(self.dsc_steps):
            with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(clip_img) # <------ ERROR HERE
                gen_img = self.decoder(z)
                gen_logits = self.discriminator(gen_img)
                ref_logits = self.discriminator(trans_img)

                dsc_cost = self.dsc_loss_fn(ref_img=ref_logits, gen_img=gen_logits)
                gp = self.gradient_penalty(batch_size, trans_img, gen_img)
                dsc_loss = dsc_cost + gp * self.gp_w

            dsc_gradient = tape.gradient(dsc_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_variables)
            self.dsc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dsc_gradient, self.discriminator.trainable_variables))

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            z_mean, z_log_var, z = self.encoder(clip_img)   # <------ ERROR ALSO HERE IF dsc_steps = 0
            gen_img = self.decoder(z)

            gen_img_logits = self.discriminator(gen_img)
            dec_loss = self.dec_loss_fn(gen_img_logits)
            kl_loss = self.kl_loss(z_mean, z_log_var)

        enc_gradient = tape.gradient(kl_loss, self.encoder.trainable_variables)
        self.enc_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(enc_gradient, self.encoder.trainable_variables))

        dec_gradient = tape.gradient(dec_loss, self.decoder.trainable_variables)
        self.dec_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(dec_gradient, self.decoder.trainable_variables))

        return {"dsc_loss": dsc_loss, "KL-Loss": kl_loss, "dec_loss": dec_loss}


class GANMonitor(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, num_img=6, latent_dim=latent_dim):
        self.num_img = num_img
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        generated_images = self.model.decoder()
        generated_images = (generated_images * 127.5) + 127.5

        for i in range(self.num_img):
            img = generated_images[i].np()
            img = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(img)
            img.save("generated_img_{i}_{epoch}.png".format(i=i, epoch=epoch))

encoder_optimizer       = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.9)
decoder_optimizer       = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.9)
discriminator_optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0002, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.9)


def discriminator_loss(real_img, fake_img):
    real_loss = tf.reduce_mean(real_img)
    fake_loss = tf.reduce_mean(fake_img)
    return fake_loss - real_loss


def generator_loss(fake_img):
    return -tf.reduce_mean(fake_img)


def kl_loss(z_mean, z_log_var):
    kl_loss = -0.5 * (1 + z_log_var - tf.square(z_mean) - tf.exp(z_log_var))
    kl_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(kl_loss, axis=1))
    return beta_v * kl_loss


def reconstruction_loss(data, reconstruction):
    rec_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.reduce_sum(keras.losses.mse(data, reconstruction), axis=(1, 2))
    )
    return rec_loss


callback = GANMonitor(num_img=3, latent_dim=latent_dim)


gan = GAN(
    discriminator=dsc_model,
    encoder=enc_model,
    decoder=dec_model,
    latent_dim=latent_dim,
    dsc_steps=dsc_steps,
)


gan.compile(
    dsc_optimizer=discriminator_optimizer,
    enc_optimizer=encoder_optimizer,
    dec_optimizer=decoder_optimizer,
    dsc_loss_fn=discriminator_loss,
    enc_loss_fn=kl_loss,
    dec_loss_fn=generator_loss,
)

gan.fit(gen_trans, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[callback])
```

I'd be very thankful for any help because I haven't been able to find or work any solution to this. I've read that in TF2.5 some errors like this shouldn't occur anymore, but using TF2.5 is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

In the original Keras example for an VAE, the encoder ends in three layers, namely z_mean, z_log_var and latent_z. While it was possible to access all terminal layers of a model in TF 2.2, as I did in my train_step

```
z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(data)
```

only (lantent_) z is committed as defined in the encoder model initialization.

By defining the model with

```
encoder_model = keras.models.Model(encoder_inputs, ([z_mean, z_log_var, latent_z]), name="encoder")
```

with a list of output layers, all z* are accessible.
I assume that getting multiple variables from a single tensor with a singular output

```
x1, x2, x3 = model(data)
```

results in a loop that might look something like:

```
for i in x:
    x{i} = model(data)
```

which is the only explaination for an iteration over a tensor I can think of.

However, reading code might be useful, I'll try to remember that.